# Why does the update operator with a non-existent key produce two separate key/values?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to use the update operator

```
  case long at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.destination.longitude -> 
 long as Number as String {format: "###.000"} 
  case lat at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.*destination.latitude -> 
 lat as Number as String {format: "###.000"} 
   case congestion at .reservations.*reservation.flight.*destination.*status! 
    -> 
 "Moderate Traffic"
  //case dest at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.*destination -> dest
}
```

Each reservation object has only one flight, with only one destination child. The status key does not exist. The result of the update operator is two separate status key/values added, one in the original destination object, but then a new empty destination object is added at the same level as the original child node.

```
"reservations":{ 
  "reservation": {
    "First Name" : "Andrea",
...
    "flight": {
      "destination": { 
   
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "status": "Moderate Traffic"
       }
      },
      "flight": {
        "destination": {
          "status": "Moderate Traffic"
        }
      }
    },
    "reservation": {
      "First Name": "Andrea",
      "Last Name": "Schmidt",
...
```

How can I adjust the selector or what conditional expression could I add to only add the missing status key/value inside original matched destination object?

Comment: Hey Ethan! Could you please provide the input payload as well as the rule that defines the destination status? Thank you!

Comment: This is a bug that we have already addressed